FLP Impossibility Result: Uniqueness of schedule application
In the proof of Lemma 2 in the FLP impossibility paper, the authors use the fact that if a single process fails after inputting distinct messages into the message buffer and then failing, any schedule applied to the resulting configurations (which they term $C_0$ and $C_1$) results in an equivalent state.

I don't quite see why both must converge upon the same state.
Perhaps I don't understand the precise formalism of a step, since it seems like it's used sometimes as a static property of the algorithm and sometimes as a dynamic property of the run. When analyzing schedules, should we assume that it is already determined as a function of each time step in the run and the current configuration what message a process can take from the message buffer?
Thanks!
FLP paper
Here's a citation to the paper:
Fischer, Michael J., et al. “Impossibility of distributed consensus with one faulty process.” Journal of the ACM, vol. 32, no. 2, Apr. 1985, pp. 374–382, https://doi.org/10.1145/3149.214121.

tl;dr Schedules determine what messages are received in each step.
To quote:

processes are deterministic, the step is completely determined by the
pair $e = (p, m)$, which we call an event. (This "event" should be
thought of as the receipt of $m$ by $p$.)


A schedule from $C$ is a [...] sequence $\sigma$ of events


Oh, so the idea is we're "simulating" the receives at each process by specifying possible steps that follow the message buffer abstraction (i.e., we only receive messages at most once, etc) and we don't actually care about the message buffer beyond its properties?

Not sure I understand your question. There's a single model of message passing concurrency used in the paper. All non-determinism is contained in the message buffer behaviour.
